# Azure Application Gateway/WAF has never been reported to Azure Security Center

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

The Application Gateway has automatically detected by Azure Security center but not showing the health status. Below is the message I got from the portal:

*Partner solution name: Application Gateway*

*Type: Saas-based Web Application Firewall*

*Integration mode: Semi-automatically provisioned*

*Status: Not reported*

*Status has never been reported to Azure Security Center. Usually, this means that this security solution isn't configured yet. It is recommended you login to the security solution management console to finalize the initial configuration*

NSG has configured as per the MS documentation.

Comment: Hi, I just tried a repro and I am able to see my AppGW Healthy. Can you share me the NSG rule set which you have defined?

Comment: Hi, Inbound rule. Allowed (65200-65535,443,80,AllowProbfromAzureLoadbalancer)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Security Center's Security Solution doesn't support WAFv2. Currently WAF (V1 SKU) is supported and you will be able to connect from there.

It is a known issue and public documentation will be updated soon to reflect this information.